# Opening web pages inside a div in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, iframe, html, modalpopup

I have a requirement of just surfing through the net in my asp application and for that purpose i dropped an iframe.

But after that i found that certain sites likes google,fb,youtube etc wont open up in iframe due to security concerns.

After some discussions with my colleagues, i thought of a solution of displaying the web page(just like iframe) in a div and then displaying that div in a modal pop up,in which the user can navigate to any pages within that modal pop up

But after some initial searching ,i havent found anything where i can start towards my aim.So, i thought of asking it here.

Can anyone guide me to a proper direction to help me achieve my aim.Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: This is what iframes are for, what are the "security concerns" you have?

Comment: Bit of a ridiculous requirement.  If people are able to access your web-based application, it's fairly clear that they'll be able to surf the web too.  What value are you getting from taking this approach?  What about the user?

Comment: Paul : User can access the web ,thats ok..but i have a requirement to allow them to navigate through my application ,and then have to do a stuff with the url

Comment: @rrrr : can u please check by adding an iframe and by opening google.com in it?

Comment: Why not just use tabbed browsing instead?

Comment: @LukeHennerley;thanks for the reply but i dnt think that will suite my rewuirement

Comment: @rrrr:Google uses the X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN header to block the site displaying in iframes.

Comment: @VipinNair If a site is preventing itself from being embedded in a  iframe by using X-Frame-Options then the only other option is to make a HTTP request, parse the response and display the content yourself. However, this will break when the user clicks a link unless you handle all links yourself. Basically, you can't do what you want to do.

Comment: you can use modal popup,http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Building-Modal-Popup-using-ASPNet-AJAX-ModalPopupExtender-Control.aspx. Though it is bit absurd to see such requirement.....

Comment: @ankur: but is there any way to open a web page in a div

Comment: process the HTTP request and parse the response in HTML, to embed it in a div.

Comment: @ankur: i want to display the full tab in the model pop is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Look at this example:

```
$('#btnShowModal').click(function () {
            $.post
            (
                'MyController',
                {
                    some parameters to pass
                },
                function (htmlResult) {
                    $('#dialogWindowContent').html('');
                    $('#dialogWindow').dialog(
                    {
                        title: 'Title',
                        autoopen: true,
                        width: 'auto',
                        //height: 180,
                        resizable: false,
                        modal: true,
                        draggable: false
                    });
                    $(window).resize(function () {
                        $("#dialogWindow").dialog("option", "position", "center");
                    });
                    //position of modalWindow will always be in center of your browser window

                    $('#dialogWindowContent').append(htmlResult);
                    $("#dialogWindow").dialog("option", "position", "center");
                });
            return false;
        });
```

It's my button and div to modal window:

```
<input type="button" value="Add theme" id="btnShowModal" />
<div id="dialogWindow">
    <div id="dialogWindowContent">
    </div>
</div>
```

I wrote it to my MVC application. And as understand, you should only rewrite post-method. As `htmlResult` you can return any html code and it will be shown in your modal window.

I hope, it will be usefull for you.

Comment: Thanks Evgenia for the Answer,but i also want a tab bar inside the dialog so that user can navigate to other pages as well in the modal pop up

Comment: Now you're adding requirements that weren't in the original question. You need to clearly state *all* the issues you're having. Since getting blocking sites to show wrapped in your own content is a large enough hurdle, I think it only fair that you start a *new* question with this arbitrarily tacked on requirement once you've solved your first issue.