# Removing the user interaction from a Javascript pop up

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, web-applications, popup

In my application I'm showing a javascript pop up with a web page in it with the help of the following code:

```
 popwin = window.open(URL, '" + id + "', 
'toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,location=0,statusbar=0,menubar=0,resizable=0,width=750,
 height=600,left = 262,top = 84');
```

which is giving me the required pop up with the web page in it.

I want to know whether there is any way to remove user interaction from this pop up and to remove the close button as well.

I will close this pop up using some timer ,but i don't want that user to be able to control the pop up. Is there any way for it?

I googled a bit but haven't got the relevant way to do it.

**Note: Can i do this using Modal Pop Up?**

Please suggest any good ways .

Comment: Sounds like user experience is in the front seat on that site ?

Comment: @adeneo: Thanks for the quick look after.Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Sure there is, but I think you need an element, like a modal, not a new window, to do it.

Comment: I think you are asking for openeing websites in ifrmaes or divs,am afraid but you can't embed a complete HTML document inside another div element as this is a block level element and W3C has defined what could be included inside it,and also major websites prevents this due to security issues.look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13817432/opening-web-pages-inside-a-div-in-asp-net/13817709#13817709

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following code.

```
popwin = window.open(URL, '" + id + "','toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,location=0,statusbar=0,menubar=0,resizable=0,width=750, height=600,left = 262,top = 84');
SetTimeOut(function(){ popwin.close()},2000);
```

Here '2000' is time in milliseconds. 2000 ms = 2sec.
Let me know if any error occurs.
You can try Telerik Radwindows.

Comment: Hi Akshay thanks for the anwser ,,but it will show the close button and also user will be able to interact with the pop up

Comment: I think it is not possible to hide close button, but this facility is available with Telerik Radwindows.

Comment: Is there any way to disable the user interaction ?

Comment: Try this link with modal popup [Modal popup without close button](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/281116/modal-dialog-without-close-button)

Comment: That is to show our application page in the modal pop up but i want to show external site in the pop up..i have researched it a lot,,but not getting anything regarding this

Comment: I think you should try Telerik's RadWindows . You can show any page in it using valid URL. It is not a free utility, but it will surve your purpose well

Answer (score 0):

You can load your content in a [Fancy Box](http://fancybox.net/) and customize the fancybox as per your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.but do that uses iframe? if yes then i cant use it as we cant open some sites in iframe since some days.Can u give me a tutorial for showing a web page in fancly box,as i am having speed issues with my internet to look into the world of net

Comment: He is asking for openeing websites in ifrmaes or divs,am afraid but you can't embed a complete HTML document inside another div element as this is a block level element and W3C has defined what could be included inside it,and also major websites prevents this due to security issues.look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13817432/opening-web-pages-inside-a-div-in-asp-net/13817709#13817709

Comment: @sajanyamaha: you can use fancybox to open iframes as well

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be more appropriate to use a CSS-like popup instead.

Working example:
http://www.pat-burt.com/csspopup.html#

As for your timer you could change the css attribute with your timer or use some jquery framework plugin like impromptu:
http://trentrichardson.com/Impromptu/

Which cost less time to deploy than the css solution I think.

Answer (score 0):

**hey man this is my popup. its not a window but acts like a window and is in jquery and javascript both.**

```
$("document").ready( function() {
var link = ""; // your link here
var d = document.createElement("div");
d.style.display = "block";
d.style.border = "1px solid #282828";
d.style.background = "#ffffff";
d.style.width = "750px";
d.style.height = "450px";
d.setAttribute("id", "popup");
var m = document.createElement("iframe");
m.setAttribute("src", link);
m.style.width = "750px";
m.style.height = "450px";
m.style.border = "0";
document.body.appendChild(d);
d.appendChild(m);
var s=0;
var n = setInterval( function() { s=s+1; if (s == 5) {
$("#popup").remove();
} }, 1000);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/APKTX/

Comment: as you have a variable id which links to the popup window so, type `var link = id;`

Comment: and also will be closed after 5 seconds!

Comment: in fiddle the link will not be opened because jsfiddle not allows it but you can done it on your domain!